# c++ linux socket server call client repeatedly

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, server, client

So I am confused on how to get a server send data back and forth with my client multiple times. Currently the server will send data to the client and then the client will send back the answer but I don't know how to do this multiple times without starting the client server again and again.

Basically I would like to know how to get a server and client to communicate repeatedly without creating a new client.

This is my server code. I am creating a random number and then using the client to determine its factors

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h> 
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int *findPrimes(int primeArray[])
{
    int i, j, n = 100000, flag;
    //int primeArray[65];
    int count = 0;

    for(i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        flag = 1;
        for(j =2;j<=i/2;j++)
        {
            if(i%j==0)
            {
                flag = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag==1)
        {
            primeArray[count] = i;
            count++;
        }
    }
    return primeArray;
}

int calcNumber()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int base = rand()%9 + 2;
    int numCalc[5];
    bool isntBase = false;
    int count = 0;
    int testNum;

    do{
        testNum = rand() % 100000;
        int number = testNum;
        cout << base << ", " << number << endl;
        count = 0;
        isntBase = false;

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            numCalc[i] = 0;
        }

        while (number > 0)
        {
            int digit = number%10;
            number /= 10;
            numCalc[count] = digit;
            count++;
            if(digit >= base)
            {
                isntBase = true;
            }
        }
    }while(isntBase == true);

    cout << testNum << "(" << base <<")";
    int decConvert = 0;
    int baseMult = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        //cout << numCalc[i] << endl;
        decConvert += numCalc[i]*(pow(base, i));
        //baseMult = baseMult * 7;
        //cout << decConvert << endl;
    }
    cout << " = " << decConvert << "(10) = ";
    return decConvert;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 

    char sendBuff[1025];
    time_t ticks; 

    int n = 3;
    int numOfPrime= 0;
    bool isPrime = false;
    bool noMorePlease = false;
    int y[9592];
    int *prime = findPrimes(y);

    int number = calcNumber();

    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
    memset(sendBuff, '0', sizeof(sendBuff)); 

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5575); 

    bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)); 

    listen(listenfd, 2); 

    int prcount = 0;

    while(noMorePlease == false){
        //Thread

        int client_socket;
        client_socket = accept(listenfd, NULL, NULL);

        int primeNum = prime[prcount];
        send(client_socket, &number, sizeof(number),0);
        send(client_socket, &primeNum,sizeof(primeNum), 0);

        int recvNum = 0;
        //char recvVal[256];   
        //recv(listenfd, &number, sizeof(number), 0);
        recv(client_socket, &recvNum, sizeof(recvNum), 0);

        //cout << endl << recvNum;

        if(recvNum >0)
        {
            cout << prime[prcount] << "^" << recvNum <<"*";
        }
        while(recvNum > 0)
        {
            number = number/prime[prcount];
            recvNum--;
        }
        prcount++;
        if(number == 1)
        {
            cout << endl;
            numOfPrime = 0;
            noMorePlease = true;
        }
        if(prcount > 9592)
        {
            numOfPrime++;
            cout << " a prime number!" << endl;
            numOfPrime++;
            if(numOfPrime == n)
            {
                noMorePlease = true;
                cout << "There were " << n << " primes in a row" << endl;
                close(listenfd);
                return 0;
            }
        }
        //close(client_socket);
    }

    close(listenfd);
    return 0;
}
```

This is my client code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h> 

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd = 0, n = 0;
    char recvBuff[1024];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 


    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("\n Usage: %s <ip of server> \n",argv[0]);
        return 1;
    } 

    memset(recvBuff, '0',sizeof(recvBuff));
    if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        printf("\n Error : Could not create socket \n");
        return 1;
    } 

    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr)); 

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5575); 

    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0)
    {
        printf("\n inet_pton error occured\n");
        return 1;
    } 

    if( connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
       printf("\n Error : Connect Failed \n");
       return 1;
    } 
    int number = 0;
    int primeNum;
    char recvVal[256];   
    recv(sockfd, &number, sizeof(number), 0);
    recv(sockfd, &primeNum, sizeof(primeNum), 0);

    int divCount = 0;

    cout << number << ", " << primeNum << endl;
    while(number % primeNum == 0)
    {
        cout << number << ",  ";
        number =  number/primeNum;
        divCount++;
    }

    cout << endl << divCount;
    send(sockfd, &divCount,sizeof(divCount), 0);

    /*
    while ( (n = read(sockfd, recvBuff, sizeof(recvBuff)-1)) > 0)
    {
        recvBuff[n] = 0;
        if(fputs(recvBuff, stdout) == EOF)
        {
            printf("\n Error : Fputs error\n");
        }
    } 

    if(n < 0)
    {
        printf("\n Read error \n");
    } 
*/
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: loop ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your client code, after the line:

```
if( connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
```

you should do the **recv** and **send** inside a loop, so that the connection stays open. When you are done, you exit the loop and close the socket. An example of this method, using synchronous sockets, can be found here: https://vcansimplify.wordpress.com/2013/03/14/c-socket-tutorial-echo-server/

Comment: Thank you very much. With a few other modifications it is working exactly how I wanted it to.

Comment: I'm glad I could help!